# Partition of a Multivariate Normal Distribution with Inverse-Wishart Covariance Prior

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution, wishart-distribution

I'm trying to partition a multivariate normal with the following structure:
$$\bf{X} = \left. \begin{bmatrix} \bf{X}_1 \\ \bf{X}_2 \end{bmatrix}\right|\Sigma \sim N_p \left(\begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix}, \Sigma =  \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\ \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} \end{bmatrix}\right)$$
$$\Sigma \sim \mathcal{W}_p^{-1}\left(\Psi = \begin{bmatrix} \Psi_{11} & \Psi_{12} \\ \Psi_{21} & \Psi_{22} \end{bmatrix}, \nu\right)$$
If I consider premultiplying $\bf{X}$ by $\begin{bmatrix} I_{n_1} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and carry through, via the multiplication properties of the multivariate Normal and Inverse Wishart, I get
$$\bf{X}_1|\Sigma_{11} \sim N_{n_1} \left(\mu_1, \Sigma_{11} \right)$$
$$\Sigma_{11} \sim \mathcal{W}_{n_1}^{-1}\left(\Psi_{11}, \nu \right)$$
Is this a valid way to find the partition, $\bf{X}_1$, of $\bf{X}$ or do I need to do something different?